# Interactive menu with "observe"

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I am testing a Shinyapp that needs a reactive SelectInput, the user selects a Transport and I need to refresh the State field, I want that appears just the States that have the selected Transport. I have 4 kinds of Transport, International_Long (8 States), International_Short (2 States), National_Short (9 States) and National_Long (All 23 States).

My code is working for the DataTable, but it´s not working for the Plot!!

The problem is when you select the "Plot" tab, the reactivity of the menu stops and appears all the States for any Transport.

Thanks in advance!!

My app: https://luisotavio.shinyapps.io/rcharts2/

My data is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jMuJ4_u7e-elB4QV9WRkRKdEU/edit?usp=sharing

reading data

```
mydata<-read.delim("mydata.txt",sep="\t",dec=",",header=TRUE)
```

ui.R

```
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')

shinyUI(
  navbarPage("TEST",

                       tabPanel("Transport Survey",
                                pageWithSidebar(
                                  headerPanel('Transport Survey'),
                                  sidebarPanel(

                                    selectInput('Transport2', 'Select a Transport:',levels(droplevels(mydata$Transport)),selected=levels(droplevels(mydata$Transport))[1]
                                    ),
                                    selectInput('State2', 'Select a State:', levels(droplevels(mydata$State)),selected=levels(droplevels(mydata$State))[1]
                                    ),

                                    width = 3

                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(
                                    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Table",dataTableOutput("mytable")),
                                    tabPanel("Plot",showOutput('myplot', 'polycharts')))
                                  )
                                )         
                       ))     

)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(rjson)
library(rCharts)



options(RCHART_WIDTH = 800)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  observe({
    TRANSPORT = input$Transport2
    updateSelectInput(session, "State2", choices = levels(droplevels(mydata$State[mydata$Transport %in% TRANSPORT])),selected = levels(droplevels(mydata$State[mydata$Transport %in% TRANSPORT]))[1]
    )
  })



  selectedData <- reactive({
    TRANSPORT = input$Transport2
    STATE = input$State2
    mydata[mydata$Transport %in% TRANSPORT  & mydata$State %in% STATE,]

  })

  output$mytable = renderDataTable({
    selectedData()
  })

  output$myplot<- renderChart2({
    mydata2<-selectedData()

    p1<-rPlot(Value ~ Company, color = 'Company', data = mydata2, type = 'bar')
    p1$guides(
      color = list(
        numticks = length(levels(droplevels(mydata2$Company)))
      ),
      y = list(
        min = 0,
        max = 10
      )
    )
    return(p1)
  })
})
```

Comment: It would really help if you made a reproducible example that didn't require downloading (not to mention installing several packages). You could start by removing sections from the code (simulate a small dataset instead of using yours, replace the graphs with trivially simple ones) and ensure the problem remains. That said, there does appear to be a curious problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your reactive by isolating `input$Transport2`:

```
  selectedData <- reactive({
    TRANSPORT = isolate(input$Transport2)
    STATE = input$State2
    mydata[mydata$Transport %in% TRANSPORT  & mydata$State %in% STATE,]

  })
```

your observer is already introducing the required dependency on `input$Transport2`:

```
  observe({
    TRANSPORT = input$Transport2
    updateSelectInput(session, "State2", choices = levels(droplevels(mydata$State[mydata$Transport %in% TRANSPORT])),selected = levels(droplevels(mydata$State[mydata$Transport %in% TRANSPORT]))[1]
    )
  })
```

The problem is the `reactive` is lazily evaluated and the `observer` is eagerly evaluated.

A better solution is to validate on data being available:

```
  selectedData <- reactive({
    TRANSPORT = input$Transport2
    STATE = input$State2
    out <- mydata[mydata$Transport %in% TRANSPORT  & mydata$State %in% STATE,]
    validate(
      need(nrow(out) > 0, 'no data')
    )
    out
  })
```

Comment: Thank you so much. For over a month I was trying to solve this problem!

Comment: You will still have a slight issue for example when you change from National:Bahia to International as Bahia is selected as first choice and no change propagates.

Comment: Have updated with a better solution which validates data being available.